# How to add "share" button to posts by App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a post schedule App for my page, but if i post from this Application i can't see the "share" button on the posts and this function is very important... How can i add this, is there any solution?

I found only codes for the share button on websites, but for the Facebook PHP SDK posts not yet...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this (i figured out):

In the posting method don't use `$facebook->api('me/feed', 'POST', $variables);`, instead use this: `$facebook->api('me/links', 'POST', $variables);`